# SQL timesamp query

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql, mysqli

I would like to select all ids from my database, which lie behind a particular date. My table looks like this:

```
id | timestamp (d.m.Y H: i)
```

this is my source code approach, which unfortunately does not work:

```
<? php
$select = mysqli_query ("SELECT id FROM log WHERE timestamp > $timestamp");
?>
```

Comment: PLease name the datatype of your timestamp column

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**`timestamp`** is a MySQL keyword , you have to escape it using backticks to be able to use it as a column name . Other than that pass variable in single qoutes

```
mysqli_query ("SELECT id FROM log WHERE `timestamp` > '$timestamp'");
```

Answer (score 1):

change

```
mysqli_query ("SELECT id FROM log WHERE timestamp > $timestamp");
```

to

```
mysqli_query ("SELECT id FROM log WHERE timestamp > '$timestamp'");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$select = mysqli_query ("SELECT id FROM log WHERE timestamp > '$timestamp'");
```